# Java Thread interruption: interrupt() vs stop()

Tags: java, multithreading, methods, interruption

I have a problem when working with thread in Java. What is the method preferred between interrupt() and stop() for interrupting a thread in Java? And why?

Thanks for any responses.

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, with the manner you posed the question, neither of them, a thread should understand by itself when it has to terminate, through a synchronized flag.

And this is done by using the `interrupt()` method, but you should understand that this 'works' only if your thread is in a waiting/sleeping state (and in this case an exception is thrown), otherwise you must check yourself, inside the run() method of your thread, if the thread is interrupted or not (with `isInterrupted()` method), and exit when you want. For instance:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        A a = new A(); //create thread object
        a.start(); //call the run() method in a new/separate thread)
        //do something/wait for the right moment to interrupt the thread
        a.interrupt(); //set a flag indicating you want to interrupt the thread

        //at this point the thread may or may not still running 

    }
}

class A extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() { //method executed in a separated thread
        while (!this.isInterrupted()) { //check if someone want to interrupt the thread
            //do something          
        } //at the end of every cycle, check the interrupted flag, if set exit
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.stop()` has been deprecated in java 8 so I would say that `Thread.interrupt()` is the way to go. There is a lengthy explanation over at [oracles site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html). It also gives a good example of how to work with threads.

Comment: The link provides many examples jamming InterruptedException within infinite cycle. Is that a proper way to handle those, or just used for illustration of Thread.stop() complications?

Comment: That's how I would do it. Basically you initiate a shutdown from some top layer and it propagates down, interrupting and marking all threads to stop (from an infinite cycle) and letting them terminate in a controlled way.

Comment: `Thread.stop()` has been deprecated for more than ten years now. The difference between Java 8 and earlier version is that `Thread.stop(Throwable)` throws `UnsupportedOperation` now.